# Is there code change required on changing the SQL Cloud Hosting Server?

Tags: sql-server, azure, amazon-web-services

I am working on Xamarin App using SQLLite / SQL DB. Plan to connect SQL Server is by using Web API Method.

I am relatively new to host SQL DB in Cloud. I am comparing Azure and Amazon. As amazon got a year worth of trial option, I am inclined towards Amazon.

My question is, Is it just connection config on changing from Amazon to Azure? Or it requires more programming work on changing the Hosting Environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes ,there might be some code changes required  like changing , unsupported TSQL syntax

For Example `SQlAzure` don't support below `TSQL`

`EXECUTE AS LOGIN` is not supported.But `EXECUTE AS USER` is supported.For a full list of not supported featutres,see this link [Transact-SQL syntax not supported in SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-transact-sql-information)

You will have to use Database Migration Assistant to assess and solve unsupported featutes ,prior to deploying in cloud

**Note:**
This is only applicable to SQLDatabase service and  not SQLServer in VM.
The above is for SQLAzure,i am not sure,if this holds good for AWS

Comment: You didn't include a link. Also, your answer only applies to SQL Database Service, not SQL Server in a VM.

Comment: Thank you David and TheGameiswar. Just on curious, Whether cloud based hosting and traditional hosting companies are different in terms of syntax ??

Comment: @goofyui:When you host in a VM,there won't be any differences for sure.Not sure about database a service ,though i believe ,it should be same in both providers